# Thetha notation proving of function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

f(n) = 4n² + 3n - 5 = Theta(n²)

How can I prove this? According to my research , this notation should be like;

for positive constants c1, c2 and n0 such that
 c1 * g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n) for all n >= n0 but I couldn't do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving Big-Theta notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464843/proving-big-theta-notation)

Comment: Theta and O notation are such concepts for which, if you formulate your question properly, you already get 50% of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have `f(n) = 4n² + 3n - 5`.

---

**Claim 1:** `f(n) <= 5n² for all n`

We have `5n² - f(n) = n² - 3n + 5 = (n - 3/2)² + (11/4) > 0` for all `n`.

**Claim 2:** `4n² <= f(n) for n >= 2`

We have `f(n) - 4n² = 3n - 5 >= 0` for `n >= 5/3 >= 2`.

---

From the above we have
`4n² <= f(n) <= 5n²` for `n >= 2`.

Compare with the big theta definition `c1 * g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * g(n)` for all `n >= n0`.

We have `c1 = 4`, `c2 = 5`, `g(n) = n²`, and, `n0 = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

First step, let's fill in the equation and see what we would need to prove.

```
c1 * n² <= 4n² + 3n - 5 <= c2 * n² (for n >= n0)
```

I will prove half of it, and leave the remainder to you.

Assume

```
c1 = 3 (since it makes sense that 3n² <= 4n² for n >= n0)
```

We need to prove that

```
3n² <= 4n² + 3n - 5
```

This is equivalent to proving

```
4n² + 3n  - 5 - 3n² >= 0 (for n >= n0)
n² + 3n - 5 >= 0
```

We know this function is a parabola, and we know the sign of the dominant term (n²) is positive. So it must be a valley-shaped parabola.

To find a suitable value for n0, we can look at the roots of the parabola. They are -1.844 and 0.844 (rounded). So assuming n0 = 2 would suffice. In short:

```
n0 >= 2  
c1 = 3  
c2 = 5
```

If you apply the same reasoning for the other half of the proof, you will get another bound for n0. Then, all you need to do is consolidate both bounds.

Answer (score 0):

4n² will grow faster than 3n² and slower than 5n². Remains to find as of which n value the inequalities hold.

From a plot, n0=2 will work.

[image]

You can show this more formally, but parabolas cannot lie.